# Getting Invalid outside procedure error

Tags: ms-access, vba

All
I am getting an error as **Invalid outside procedure error** in VBA for **Set MyAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")** can anyone please help me out of this error.TIA

`Dim MyAccess As Access.Application
Set MyAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
MyAccess.Visible = True
MyAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase ("E:\Bharath Files\Bharath 2015-2016\New folder")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this call within either a sub or a function.

```
Function TestApp() As Boolean

    Dim MyAccess As Access.Application 

    Set MyAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    MyAccess.Visible = True

    MyAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase <Database File to Open>

    TestApp = True

End Function
```

When you run this function a new instance of Access will open with your database but as soon as you get to the end of the function it will terminate because your declaration of 'MyAccess' will fall out of scope.

If you want your database to remain open after the function has run you will need to declare your 'MyAccess' outside the routine in the Declarations section of the code module.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question, It was helpful and useful for me :)